# Oracle Delete Operation Taking Forever

Tags: oracle, performance, transactions

I'm trying to use this code, but it takes hours to run:

```
create table tmp$_mkemp_2 (id number generated by default on null as identity primary key, c1 varchar2 (30), c2 varchar2 (30))
/

set timing on serveroutput on size unlimited linesize 32767 pagesize 50000 trimspool on tab off feedback on heading on verify on
define svTableName = tmp$_mkemp_2
define svInsertHowMany = 500000
define svFetchRate = 2000
define svUpdateWhichMod = 2
define svDeleteWhichMod = 10
col ts format a20
col cnt format a10
<<s01_row_by_row_rbr_dml>> begin <<rbr_loop>> for iRec in (select dbms_random.string ('p', 10) c1, level id from dual connect by level <= &svInsertHowMany) loop
          insert into &svTableName (c1) values (iRec.c1);
          if mod (iRec.id, &svFetchRate) = 0 then commit; end if; end loop rbr_loop; commit;
     <<update_loop>> for iUpdateRec in (select id, c1 from &svTableName) loop
          update &svTableName set c2 = substr (c1, 1, 2) || ' ## ' || id where mod (id, &svUpdateWhichMod) = 0 and id = iUpdateRec.id;
          if mod (iUpdateRec.id, &svFetchRate) = 0 then commit; end if; end loop update_loop; commit;
     <<delete_loop>> for iDeleteRec in (select id, c1 from &svTableName) loop
          delete &svTableName where id = iDeleteRec.id and mod (iDeleteRec.id, &svDeleteWhichMod) = 0;
          if mod (iDeleteRec.id, &svFetchRate) = 0 then commit; end if; end loop delete_loop; commit;
     end s01_row_by_row_rbr_dml;
/
select to_char (sysdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts from dual
/
select count (0) cnt from &svTableName
/
```

When I check the table count from another session, it shows 450,000 which means the `delete_loop` has finished. This takes about 10 minutes, *but the process continues to run for hours after that*.

**Why is the transaction in the original session continuing to run after the work is complete?**

The problem appears to be reproducible with a smaller dataset. For example, with 50,000 rows, the deletion is done after about 1 minute (the table now shows as having 45,000 rows) but the full process takes 6 minutes to complete.

I am aware this is the wrong approach to data processing, but I want to understand the specifics of the runtime performance of this approach.

Comment: Why are you processing data in loops? A set-oriented processing should be better/faster option. As of question itself: did another session modify data you're trying to delete? If so, your DELETE is waiting for another session to COMMIT (or ROLLBACK) before it can continue.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is the worst possible way to process data. I agree.

What I am doing is trying to provide management with benchmarks to compare doing it this way, vs. doing it will Bulk Data Processing (FETCH ... BULK COLLECT INTO ... FORALL DELETE, etc.). Presently they are being told this way is "good enough". I am trying to make the case that this way is horrible, and for no reason and for no benefit.

Converting all our procedures to true SQL would be a heavy lift for our team. I don't think anyone is really proficient with SQL, beyond being able to write basic SELECT ...

Comment: ... statements.

If I followed my intended logic here correctly, I intend to have this loop 500k times through for INSERT, 500k times through for UPDATE and 500k times through for DELETE.

It's the DELETE that is taking 95% of the time. I am dumbfounded by this. Not at all what I expected.

In other tests, I separate the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE in their own independent blocks, and in those cases, the ROW-BY-ROW SLOW-BY-SLOW method is indeed significantly slower then the BULK COLLECT method but not THAT MUCH slower. Something around 2x - 5x performance difference. It's the ...

Comment: ... DELETE that is around 95% slower in the ROW-BY-ROW method vs. the BULK COLLECT (for 50k records 6 min. vs. 3.x seconds ... something like that).

But even in that case when I check the row count of the table from another session, it appears to finish all its DELETES relatively quickly - judging by row count - and yet the code just keeps runnning for a very long time, before finally finishing in the original session.

This is a generic dummy test table, with dummy test code. This whole scenario is only for benchmarking the 2 different methodologies for transforming ...

Comment: ... data: "ROW-BY-ROW SLOW-BY-SLOW" vs. BULK COLLECT WITH FORALL DML. It is not possible there could be another session doing anything with this table.

Thank you for comment and insight and for taking the time to share it. If you have any further suggestion or ideas, I will be equally grateful.

Comment: It all depends on what you're doing. If you are looping a small number of times and have to do atomic transactional changes within each loop, row-by-row is the best method. If you are looping millions of times, not so much. And FORALL and BULK COLLECT are nto the fastest methods, for both of those interface SQL with the PL/SQL engine. The fastest is to keep the data entirely within SQL and not use PL/SQL on a row level. Think INSERT SELECT, MERGE, CREATE TABLE AS SELECT, etc.. all of which can be parallelized and direct path. FORALL and BULK COLLECT cannot.

Comment: But bulk methods provide less control (error handling, code branching, complex loop-based or recursive processing, etc..). Great for warehouse-style data aggregation, summarization, reporting, etc.. not so much for critical source-of-record core business processes. There's a tradeoff between minute control (PL/SQL row-by-row) and throughput (bulk methods) and choosing the right one entirely depends on your particular use-case and data.

Comment: @Paul W BULK COLLECT cannot be parallelized and direct path'd. Those are excellent points. Thank you!!

Comment: @Paul W Thank you for your comments and insight, and for taking the time to share them. I appreciate it very. Those are excellent points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```
for iDeleteRec in (select id, c1 from &svTableName) loop
          delete &svTableName where mod (id, &svDeleteWhichMod) = 0;
```

Is looping a half million times. Within each loop, you are doing a separate delete operation and your only predicate is a modulus function. Did you perhaps omit the `and id = iDeleteRec.id` predicate to mirror what you did for the update?

The current code is deleting more than you intend, and furthermore cannot use an index to do so.

Comment: You make some excellent points. Thank you.

The index thing. Excellent point.

I do still find it strange that from a different session, all the DELETES (10%) show as being complete.

And yet, the statement continues to run another 5 minutes (when using 50k as opposed to 500k records).

And FWIW, the BULK COLLECT FORALL DML option on the exact same operation is very fast. Whatever is slowing this thing down so much is not in effect when using BULK COLLECT FORALL DML.

Thank you for your insight and taking the time to share it.

If you have any further ideas Ill be equally grateful.

Comment: @M.Kemp I think if you added the `and id = iDeleteRec.id` to your delete statement the mystery would go away. The lack of this predicate is causing more rows to be deleted per execution than you intend, which is why it appears from another session that the rows have all been deleted, but you still have more loops to go. You just keep trying to delete the same rows over and over again, that's why. Add the missing predicate and it'll work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I appreciate your insight and expertise. I'll show what I've done:

```
WHERE ID = ID + MOD (ID, &svDeleteWhichMod)
```

What do you think. It seems good to me. ID is a PRIMARY KEY. I forgot to mention that in the original post. I'll probably go back and add it now.

Thanks again.

Comment: I have added the CREATE TABLE Source Code to the original post.

Comment: It took me forever to figure out what you were saying. But you are right!! I don't EXACTLY know what was going on with the runaway transaction, because when I used a small number of iterations (<=10k) it did eventually finish. So I don't think it is PRECISELY true to say that it keeps trying to delete the same rows over an over. HOWEVER it was true that I was deleting many rows on the first iteration of the loop, when I only intended to delete one at a time.

The way I eventually figured this out on my side was a put a PRAGMA_AUTONOMOUS local procedure in the code block and ...

Comment: ... recorded the ID's at every iteration. Then I compared which records were in my PRAGMA_AUTONOMOUS table vs. the ones left in the master table, after the loop was complete, and all the deletions done.

But having

```
delete &svTableName where id = id + mod (id, &svDeleteWhichMod) 
```
 was DEFINITELY the problem. I have fixed it in the OP above.

Thanks again.